# What is the purpose of this microwave platter with outer ring for water?

Tags: equipment, microwave

I recently inherited a platter for use in the microwave. It is made of plastic and has a channel around the perimeter for water.

[image]

Its markings read:

- FOR MICROWAVE OVEN ONLY.
- DO NOT USE WITHOUT FOOD AND WATER.
- USE WATER 30 ml DURING COOKING.
- DO NOT HEAT MORE THAN 8 min.

FWIW, the outer lip is 10.75 inches in diameter and my plastic cover for reheating stuff (which fits a standard dinner plate) fits just inside the lip. That is, the water is under the dome with the food.

At first I thought it might be some sort of steamer, but now I wonder if the water is intended to be a "dummy load", similar to reheating foods like pizza along with a glass of water to help prevent the crust from getting soggy.

Has anyone else seen a contraption like this? What is its intended purpose?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  And thank you for sharing a weird cooking gadget.  However ... it seems like you don't actually have a question?

Comment: Hi Gord, as FuzzyChef said: I think we need a clear formulation of your question. I read your text through, and I also didn't see what you want answered.

Comment: FWIW, I looked up both steamer and sterilizer desings, but didn't see any like the plate you have.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it might be part of a microwave steamer.

It looks a bit shallow, but it seems to be the lower plate where water pools before cooking, and may be part of a several peace set that can be stacked on top of each other to form multiple "floors".

The lip may be part of the locking mechanism that holds them together.

Either part of a "shallow" steamer for smaller quantities similar to
[image]

Or part of a stackable set like
[image]